# Select substring faster performance than select column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an error in my application and found something that I don't understand.

One of my columns has the type `nvarchar(max)` and contains strings with a length of 65k chars.

Selecting the column in my query causes a performance issue,

```
SELECT Id
       ,Description
       ,DescriptionForUser
FROM MyTable
```

The query takes 15 sec to execute, but when using `substring(colname,1,100000)`

```
SELECT Id
       ,Description
       ,SUBSTRING(DescriptionForUser,1,100000)
FROM MyTable
```

The query execution takes under a second.

What causes this performance change?

Comment: How big is the `DescriptionForUser` column? Does it contain lots of data?

Comment: I *assume* that's the 65,000 character column they talk about, @DavidG .

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, It seems that way, but for all rows to contain 65k chars seems weird. I wonder what the result of `LEN(DescriptionForUser)` would actually return.

Comment: not all rows contain that long descriptions, some are empty or have just 1k to 2k characters, the table also has a column packageId, filtering the query for the packages with short description executes fine, just packages with long descriptions couse problems

Comment: Returning *a lot* of rows with *very* long values is generally expensive, @TomekZakrzewski . It's normally unlikely that you need to return *lots* of rows with 10k+ characters. How many rows is your query above returning? Where are you running that query (in SSMS)? What are you doing with that data afterwards?

Comment: It would be interesting to calculate the length on each row on that field and sum it up see what the total character count.

Comment: yes i am using SSMS, the query returns just 4 rows

Comment: Remembering issues with union quieres in SQL Server, it would just be like them to really allocate 2 GB per row for the first query and then run into memory issues.

Comment: I quite don't understand why using the substring function has that of an impact on the query performance, in both cases the whole description is returned

Comment: Is `MyTable` a table or is it a view?

Comment: MyTable is a table

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your question and comments. As I understand it, you have  have only 4 rows in the table and it takes 15 seconds without `SUBSTRING`?

Comment: @TomekZakrzewski   I just did the same exercise on one of my account tables.  ~1.6 mil records no index raw table.  23 seconds without the function and 20 seconds with it, so it did pick up some performance using it.   Interesting.

Comment: @DanGuzman The complete number of rows is 1800, but after filtering out the rows for a specific package (the query is missing the packageId column) the number of rows returned is 4

Comment: I suspect (as I just realised) you are probably seeing the difference between logical and physical io. What happens if you use `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` before each?

Comment: @TomekZakrzewski, that makes more sense. The queries in your question have no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Execution plan with substring applied to text field, Select 0 cost, compute scalar 1 % cost index scalar non clustered 99%

Without the substring function it goes from select to index scan nonclustered.  

The substring applied improved performance by 2 seconds.  19 to 21 this time....

Comment: @TomekZakrzewski, upload the actual execution plans to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.